# ¿Cómo clonar un select en una tabla si las filas son agregadas mediante el método append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy haciendo un proyecto el cual tengo una tabla que sus filas que se agregan mediante el método de append, entonces lo que yo quiero es que cada vez que agrego una fila se clona el primer combo que se encuentra en la tabla de la columna descripción, entonces necesito clonar así sucesivamente para los restos filas que se agregarán mas adelante , solo he podido clonar para la segunda fila y si quiero agregar la tercera fila me surge el problema, y se clona en la misma fila como se puede ver en el resultado.. 
por favor ayúdenme aun no soy experto en javascript, se les agradece de antemano..

```js
function addrows() {
  var contador = 1;
  contador++;
  var row = '<tr id="rols">' +
    '<td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '<td>' +
    '<select name="" id="" class="form-control">' +
    '<option value="">option 1</option>' +
    '<option value="">option 2</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td id="sel' + contador + '">' +

    '</td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $("#rows").append(row);
}

function clon() {
  addrows();
  $("#descripciones").clone().appendTo("#sel2");
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Proyecto</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin:0 auto;">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="clon();">Agregar</button>
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ITEM</th>
          <th>CANTIDAD</th>
          <th>UNIT MEDIDA</th>
          <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
          <th>VAL COMPRA</th>
          <th>IGV</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="rows">
        <tr id="rols">
          <td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">option 1</option>
                      <option value="">option 2</option>
                    </select>
          </td>
          <td id="tbodyDescripcion">
            <select name="idDescripcion" id="descripciones" class="form-control descripciones">
            <option value="">option 1</option>
                      <option value="">option 2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

El error se encuentra en que tienes fijo el id de la fila a la que le agregas el select, intenta manejando la variable contador en un nivel superior para que sea accesible desde ambas funciones y así manejes el contador de manera global :

```js
var contador = 1;
    function addrows() {
      contador++;
      var row = '<tr id="rols">' +
      '<td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<select name="" id="" class="form-control">' +
      '<option value="">option 1</option>' +
      '<option value="">option 2</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td id="sel' + contador + '">' +

      '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '</tr>';
      $("#rows").append(row);
    }

    function clon() {
      addrows();
      $("#descripciones").clone().appendTo("#sel"+contador);
    };
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Proyecto</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin:0 auto;">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="clon();">Agregar</button>
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ITEM</th>
          <th>CANTIDAD</th>
          <th>UNIT MEDIDA</th>
          <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
          <th>VAL COMPRA</th>
          <th>IGV</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="rows">
        <tr id="rols">
          <td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
              <option value="">option 1</option>
              <option value="">option 2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td id="tbodyDescripcion">
            <select name="idDescripcion" id="descripciones" class="form-control descripciones">
              <option value="">option 1</option>
              <option value="">option 2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Eso responde a tu pregunta, pero te recomiendo hacerlo de la siguiente manera, ya que el id del select se repetirá y te provocara más errores

```js
 var contador = 1;
    function addrows() {
      contador++;
      var row = '<tr id="rols">' +
      '<td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<select name="" id="" class="form-control">' +
      '<option value="">option 1</option>' +
      '<option value="">option 2</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td id="sel' + contador + '">' +

      '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>' +
      '</tr>';
      $("#rows").append(row);
    }

    function clon() {
      addrows();
      var estructuraSelect = "<select name=\"idDescripcion" + contador + "\" id=\"descripciones" + contador + "\" class=\"form-control descripciones\">";
      var selectActual = $("#descripciones1").html();
      estructuraSelect += selectActual + "</select>"
      alert(estructuraSelect);
            $("#sel"+contador).html(estructuraSelect);
    };
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Proyecto</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin:0 auto;">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="clon();">Agregar</button>
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ITEM</th>
          <th>CANTIDAD</th>
          <th>UNIT MEDIDA</th>
          <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
          <th>VAL COMPRA</th>
          <th>IGV</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="rows">
        <tr id="rols">
          <td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
              <option value="">option 1</option>
              <option value="">option 2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td id="tbodyDescripcion">
            <select name="idDescripcion1" id="descripciones1" class="form-control descripciones">
              <option value="">option 1</option>
              <option value="">option 2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</html>
```

De esta manera tendrás cada select identificado, cambie un poco el código final pero la idea es la misma.